# Wiring for Bedroom - how to express design to electrician

Tags: electrical, lighting, bedroom

I bought my first flat a couple of months ago in north London and for my first bit of redecoration I wish to get my bedroom up to a really nice standard.

Before i go into picking out wall coverings etc I know I want to re-wire the room a bit better.The flat was built in the 1970s by the local authority. It became private about 15 years ago but hasnt really had a lot invested in terms of wiring or plumbing so as a result these aspects are a bit basic (think water pipes showing on the walls and not covered very well in places). I do know the electrics are safe though and had an EICR done recently.

Currently there's a light on a dimmer switch and three sockets in the corner of the room (nowhere near the bed) with no switches on them. I want to wire to have double sockets inc USB each side of the bed, another set where i might put a dressing table and possibly wall lights on each side of the bed with switches for those and the main light next to the bedsides.

I'd like to get quotes from a few electricians but id assume i need some sort of way to easily describe what i want.

What is the best way to illustrate this to potential electricians? Is there some kind of diagram I should try to put together?

Has anyone experience of commissioning a similar thing and got tips for sites for advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If they will be visiting in person, put pictures on the wall of exactly what you want, exactly where you want it. If not, make drawings, and on the drawings, include what is there now.

Comment: Show the electrician what you just typed if he/she can't comprehend you don't want them doing the work. Put painters tape in the locations you would like the outlets and switches, they may need to be moved several inches because of the framing. This should give you exactly what you want.

Comment: One thing our Yankee contributors should understand, in the UK they rarely use our lumber and drywall construction methods, because they don't have the lumber.  Stone, brick and concrete are dominant methods.   Wiring tends to be a lot more surface-mount.   As such, putting outlets where you please can be non-trivial.  Despite EU membership they're just fine with inches. They invented them.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest just break it down into a list of items. So you can clearly discuss each item ( this example may help )

**Changes to existing electrical installation.**
**Lighting**
1. 2x Dimmable Lights positioned on the wall either side of the bed. 
2. 2x Dimmer/Switches to control these lights positioned on the wall either side of the bed.
3. Two way switching for main room light. One switch located near the entrance to the room, the second switch located positioned on the wall near the bed.

**Power Outlets**
All outlets to switched double plates with a USB charge point.
4. Existing power outlets relocated one either side of the bed.
5. switch Dbl Outlet near Dressing table.

Location of each point to be confirmed and identified during site inspection before any work begins.

Hope this helps :-)
Most Sparkies are easy to get along with provided they have a clear understanding of what you want and don't change your mind after the work has begun.

Comment: Even if they change there mind it is not a problem because that cost more :)